# How to set a different background color for a specific tab in the TabView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I want to change the background color of the tab bar only when a specific tab is selected, while keeping the default background color for the other tabs.

Is this possible with the default TabView, or do I need to create a custom tab bar?